# Figuring the angle of a cut

Tags: wood

I have a 2x4 that is 86 inches long which needs to be cut so that one end is 2 inches and the opposite end 1.75 inches.  How do I figure the angle of the cut?  Could you please give me the step by step process of figuring this?  To tell me to subtract one side from another and apply the law of sines to the result will not help since I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I think most people don't "calculate the cut" but would first cut the item to length, then mark 2" on one end, and 1.73" on the other, then use a chalk line, straight edge, string etc to make the whole length. Something shorter could be cut on a table saw with a sled, but again, less calculation, more measure, mark, cut.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: Isherwood, someone wanting to cut a board to fit a specific space or application sounds like on topic to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a triangle with one side of 2" and another side of 1.75".

The first thing you want to do is find the hypotenuse.  Use the Pythagorean theorem.

a^2 + b^2 = c^2
2^2 + 1.75^2 = c^2
4 + 3.0625 = c^2
sqrt(7.0625) = c
2.65 = c

Next we will use **arcsin** or **arccos** to find the angles.  Make sure your calculator is set to degrees, not radians.  The angles you calculate should add up to about 90*.  All triangles have their angles add up to 180*, and this is a right triangle, so there is a given that one side is 90*.

arcsin(2/2.65) = 49.0*
arcsin(1.75/2.65)= 41.32
49 + 41.32 = 90.32
OR
arccos(2/2.65) = 40.9
arccos(1.75/2.65)= 48.6
40.9 + 48.6 = 89.5

source: http://www.mathopenref.com/triginverse.html

Answer (score 0):

The wedge being ripped off is 86" long and has a slope of 0.25", right?

If so then, the answer is 0.167° based on [this online calculator](http://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html?vc=&vx=0.25&vy=&va=90&vz=86&vb=&angleunits=d&x=58&y=8).

[image]

By the way, the law of sines means, look it up in a table or use a calculator. The tangent (to look up) equals the opposite divided by the adjacent... so get a trig book and look up the angle of a tangent for 0.25/86 and you will find the angle is 0.167°. Here's a [tangent calculator](http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Tan_Calculator.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Since it seems like you're working with an existing space [these](https://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A228013%2Ck%3Aangle%20finder%20tool) work wonders if you're looking for an angle... but you're not, you're looking for an edge length.

What actually needs is a straight ruler. Place it on the edge of the 2x4 and rotate to 2", mark it off, and cut, followed by putting it in place, marking off the end edge and using the ruler and rotate on the edge to measure a 1.75" line from that point and mark it off.

Comment: -1 because answers that depend solely on a link are not desired on Stack Exchange sites. Then yet this attempt at an answer points to some retail store page with no explanation of what the OP is looking at.

Comment: It's an overly complicated request, using an angle find is the simplest, cheapest, and fastest solution for this poster. Could you explain how an angle find doesn't give him the angle that he's looking for?

Comment: A quarter inch difference over a distance of over seven feet? Using a tool with an adjustable leg that is maybe only four, six or eight inches long could be off a goodly amount just by lining by the the fuzzy side or wide line.

Comment: You're right, even I overcomplicated the question, I edited my response. Thanks Michael